# Tkinter won't show image even with an additional reference set

Tags: python, tkinter

I know the most common problem with `Tkinter` not showing an image is that garbage collector deletes the image resulting in a blank space in place of the image. However I have set the additional reference as suggested in many posts about this. The image is still not showing on my application.

```
photo = PhotoImage("image.jpg", width=40, height=20)

label = Label(self, image=photo)
label.image = photo #reference
label.pack()
```

My image is blank - white. What else could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have tried using `PIL`'s `ImageTk` as suggested in the following manner:

```
image = Image.open("image.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(self, image=photo)

self.start_page_image = photo  # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

The image definitely is in the same folder but I again get a white rectangle instead of the actual image.

Should I not use label to show the image? The documentation states that you should be able to use it with any widget that accepts image as a parameter.

But it also states that I should use a `PIL` image. What is a `PIL` image? Should I not be able to use png formats with it?

I am referring to this documentation: (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html). I have `Pillow` installed instead of `PIL` as I could not install `PIL` with `pip`.

This does work with jpg format. However I want to preserve the transparency of some pixels which I wanted to do with a png image. Should I open a png image differently?

Comment: Try and show a complete example. There could be lots missing but you have not shown a working example. Are you actually running the mainloop? `label.image` here is redundant as the construction sets that. Try assigning it to `self.imagereference` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I have tried assigning it to self.image_reference, although with no difference. Yes, I am running the mainloop, I do have a working application with labels, buttons etc. and I do get a white blank rectangle on a colored background where the image was supposed to be, so the code does get executed. However the image isn't supposed to be white.

Comment: Does image reside in same folder as script as assumed per your code?

Comment: Tkinter's `PhotoImage` simply does not support JPEG.  You need to use PIL/Pillow's `ImageTk.PhotoImage` class instead, which supports a much wider range of image formats.

Comment: I will try this, thank you!

Comment: I have tried it but have some troubles with how should I use it. Please see my edited post for details. I would appreciate help very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to open an image as well as support the transparent look of the image.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="slika.gif")
label = ttk.Label(self, image=photo)

self.start_page_image = photo
label.pack()
```

I use the `Label` from `ttk's` library because I am already using its widgets and frames. When I use it this way, the background around the image (the transparent parts of the image) is the same color as the whole application.

`PIL`'s `PhotoImage` did not open png files for me and I had to convert them to gif format. I figured I can use `tkinter`'s default library `PhotoImage` if I will be using only gif formats.